# What is the most popular way to implement configuration settings like about:config in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, configuration-management

I would like to implement/use-existing a cross platform configuration settings tool like `about:config` in Firefox. It would have to work on Windows and Mac. Are there any libraries or design patterns out there that people recommend?

Also, if I were to use a library, it would have to be "free as in beer" and couldn't be a GPL license. The apache license would be ok.

The Windows side uses C++/MFC and the Mac side uses Objective-C. The configuration file would have to be read on both platforms, but they don't have to share the same library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties files/ini files.

- Python has a library. ([Config Parser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html))
- C++ probably quite a few, but this is a top google hit. ([RudeConfig](http://rudeserver.com/config/))
- Java has [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/)
- .NET has [nini](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2004/07/03/348.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but RudeConfig is under the GNU license.